# Can I animate the change of a background gradient?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, gradient

I'm trying to make the gradient fade in as the background color.

```
$('body').animate({
  background: '-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(#b0c4ff),to(#6289ff)) fixed)'
}, 2000, function(){});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/myLf9o0j/3/

[jQuery animate backgroundColor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190560/jquery-animate-backgroundcolor)

[Animation in css with gradient colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13764386/animation-in-css-with-gradient-colors)

Comment: You want it to fade in from white?  Or do you want it to fade from color to color?  If you want it to fade in to white, just animate the element opacity and make sure it has a white element behind it (usually body)

Comment: Not using `jQuery .animate()` AFAIK.

Comment: From color to color.

Comment: You should be able to use https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color/.  I haven't played with gradients though

Comment: Remover the ')' after 'fixed'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a full page div and add it on the background behind all other elements.
Then you can make it animate.

Check the code below:

```js
function goodMorning(){
 $('#background').animate({
            opacity: 1
 }, 2000);
}

goodMorning();
```

```css
body{
    background-color: red;
}
#background{
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    z-index: -1;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(#b0c4ff),to(#6289ff)) fixed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="background"></div>
<p>Hello :)</p>
```